# Strange issue with me. statement in Access - Stopping after 10th option

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a pulldown text field with 15 options - Package 1, Package 2, through to Package 15.

Once a user selects a pulldown, the on change procedure is such that it populates the the fields in the form with the cooresponding data pulled in the select statement as the source of the pull down.

It works great until the user selects Package 10 or greater.  the result is blank fields.  Not exactly sure why and how to fix this.

```
Private Sub ColourPackage_Change()
Me.Brick.Value = Me.ColourPackage.Column(1)
Me.Stone.Value = Me.ColourPackage.Column(2)
Me.Shingles.Value = Me.ColourPackage.Column(3)
Me.Windows.Value = Me.ColourPackage.Column(4)
Me.GarageDoors.Value = Me.ColourPackage.Column(5)
Me.BoardBatton.Value = Me.ColourPackage.Column(6)
Me.Alluminum.Value = Me.ColourPackage.Column(7)
Me.Stucco.Value = Me.ColourPackage.Column(8)
Me.Shakes.Value = Me.ColourPackage.Column(9)
Me.Railing.Value = Me.ColourPackage.Column(10)
End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe you mean 'ComboBox' or 'ListBox' instead of 'pulldown text'? Which is it? Does it allow multi-select?

Comment: Sorry, ComboBox is correct.

Comment: Can you give details of what is there at the RowSource of combobox ColourPackage ? There must a table being used for the SQL of RowSource, can you provide some sample data in the fields....the fields in the table might be blank, so they are not bringing data....So you mean the Br

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the *AfterUpdate* event:

```
Private Sub ColourPackage_AfterUpdate()
```

Comment: I will give it a shot.  Funny enough, if I change the ComboBox item from Package 10 to Package10 (removing the space), it will work.  But, I can leave Package 9 with a space and it will work.

Comment: Why put spaces in control names, fields or table names - it just makes you have to surround references to controls and field names with brackets all the time leading to typo's and difficult to read code.